# Making sure Accordion tabs are independent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a website to display information on different athletes. Currently the way I'm trying to do it is make each player their own tab of an accordion. Then you drop the accordion down upon click, and you have these tabs where you can filter for the information you're looking for. However, the way I did it initially was have the JavaScript grab the unique ID's for each tab. I quickly found out when making the 2nd player that obviously ID's weren't going to work as the 2nd accordion tab would open the 1st accordion's information. I tried changing it to class instead, but that's now leaving it unresponsive. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Looking for any assistance as to how to fix the JavaScript code to grab the correct tab. I've tried like `this.` and it doesn't respond to that either to try and single out the tab being clicked.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}

function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementByClassName(tabName).style.display = "block";
    this.evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 10px 5px 18px 5px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h3 {
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<button class="accordion"><h3>1. Player Number 1</h3></button>
  <div class="panel">
      <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Position')">Position</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Positives')">Positives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Negatives')">Negatives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Overall')">Overall</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Comparison')">Comparison</button>
        </div>

        <div class="Position tabcontent">
          <h3>Position</h3>
          <p>asdfasfsadfff</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Positives tabcontent">
          <h3>Positives</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Negatives tabcontent">
          <h3>Negatives</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Overall tabcontent">
          <h3>Overall</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Comparison tabcontent">
          <h3>Comparison</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><h3>2. Player Number 2</h3></button>
  <div class="panel">
      <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Position')">Position</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Positives')">Positives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Negatives')">Negatives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Overall')">Overall</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Comparison')">Comparison</button>
        </div>

        <div class="Position tabcontent">
          <h3>Position</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Positives tabcontent">
          <h3>Positives</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Negatives tabcontent">
          <h3>Negatives</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Overall tabcontent">
          <h3>Overall</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Comparison tabcontent">
          <h3>Comparison</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><h3>3. Player Number 3</h3></button>
  <div class="panel">
      <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Position')">Position</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Positives')">Positives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Negatives')">Negatives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Overall')">Overall</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Comparison')">Comparison</button>
        </div>

        <div class="Position tabcontent">
          <h3>Position</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="Positives tabcontent">
          <h3>Positives</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="Negatives tabcontent">
          <h3>Negatives</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="Overall tabcontent">
          <h3>Overall</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="Comparison tabcontent">
          <h3>Comparison</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Just get the `panel` div of the selected accordion and select the element with the class and work around it. But once the accordion is closed, the previously selected tab in the accordion remains selected, that case need to be handled accordingly.

P.S : Please [refer this article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) on how to implement a single event listener for multiple elements instead of iterating the NodeList. Just for optimization.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}

function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    var panel = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;  panel.querySelector("."+tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.target.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 10px 5px 18px 5px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h3 {
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<button class="accordion"><h3>1. Player Number 1</h3></button>
  <div class="panel">
      <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Position')">Position</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Positives')">Positives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Negatives')">Negatives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Overall')">Overall</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Comparison')">Comparison</button>
        </div>

        <div class="Position tabcontent">
          <h3>Position</h3>
          <p>asdfasfsadfff</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Positives tabcontent">
          <h3>Positives</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Negatives tabcontent">
          <h3>Negatives</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Overall tabcontent">
          <h3>Overall</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Comparison tabcontent">
          <h3>Comparison</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><h3>2. Player Number 2</h3></button>
  <div class="panel">
      <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Position')">Position</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Positives')">Positives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Negatives')">Negatives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Overall')">Overall</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Comparison')">Comparison</button>
        </div>

        <div class="Position tabcontent">
          <h3>Position</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Positives tabcontent">
          <h3>Positives</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Negatives tabcontent">
          <h3>Negatives</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Overall tabcontent">
          <h3>Overall</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>

        <div class="Comparison tabcontent">
          <h3>Comparison</h3>
          <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
        </div>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><h3>3. Player Number 3</h3></button>
  <div class="panel">
      <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Position')">Position</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Positives')">Positives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Negatives')">Negatives</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Overall')">Overall</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Comparison')">Comparison</button>
        </div>

        <div class="Position tabcontent">
          <h3>Position</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="Positives tabcontent">
          <h3>Positives</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="Negatives tabcontent">
          <h3>Negatives</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="Overall tabcontent">
          <h3>Overall</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="Comparison tabcontent">
          <h3>Comparison</h3>
          <p></p>
        </div>
  </div>
```